# HTML How to show an <iframe> when a button is pressed

Tags: html, iframe

Ive been using geolocation and HTML recently, i want to try to show an iframe when the submit button is pressed, i keep getting stuck on what to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onClick="javascript: window.open('https://api.ipdata.co/' + document.getElementById('text').value);" />

</body>
</html>
```

Oh and here’s my iframe
    
The IPadress is the ipadress of a device i am testing this out on. I want to put this in where the “javascript: window.open” is

Comment: Don't use inline JS. It's hard to maintain. use `<script>` and `Element.addEventListener()`

Comment: And most importantly... where is your `<iframe>` in HTML?

Comment: Sorry, i messed up, i edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why You'd want to show an iframe with a JSON response...

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text"),
    btn = document.getElementById("btn"),
    iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");

function text2iframe() {
  iframe.src = "https://api.ipdata.co/" + text.value;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", text2iframe);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" value="47.91.202.22"><br>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit"><br>
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

When you can go for the JSON directly!

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text"),
  btn = document.getElementById("btn"),
  pre = document.getElementById("pre");

function ipdata() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', "https://api.ipdata.co/" + text.value, true);
  request.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      pre.textContent = request.responseText
      var responseObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      console.log( responseObj.country_name )
      console.dir( responseObj );
    } else {
      // error
    }
  });
  request.addEventListener("error", function() {
    // connection error
  });
  request.send();
}

btn.addEventListener("click", ipdata);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" value="47.91.202.22"><br>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit"><br>
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```